# Android add action only to Heads up notification and not in the notification drawer

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to add action to Notification which should only show up in Heads up Notification. In the notification drawer i am using inbox style for the notifications and dont want the action button there. If i add action it is being shown in both the places.

I also tried to set a custom layout like following but notification.headsUpContentView is always returning null :

```
RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.headsup_notification);
builder.setContent(view); // I know this is not right, but tried
notification = builder.build();
RemoteViews headsupView = notification.headsUpContentView;
```

Can someone please help me get actions or add a custom layout for heads up notifications alone and not in the notification bar?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, can you just build two notifications, one with an action, the other without?

Comment: If i build two notifications, the same notification will be shown twice in Notification bar one with action and one without. I am trying to get similar behavior like the samsung native Message app. In Heads up notification new message shows up with 3 actions, and in the notifcation drawer it is different, inbox style with 2 actions. Similarly i want one action in Headsup and no actions in notification drawer.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?